# What is a better method to solve this prob?

Tags: algorithm, search, time, dynamic-programming

Here is the problem i am trying to solve,

> You are given a table with 2 rows and N columns. Each cell has an integer in it. The score
>   of such a table is denfined as follows: for each column, consider the sum of the two numbers
>   in the column; the maximum of the N numbers so obtained is the score. For example, for
>   the table
>
> 7 1 6 2
>   1 2 3 4
>
> the score is max(7 + 1; 1 + 2; 6 + 3; 2 + 4) = 9.
>   The first row of the table is fixed, and given as input. N possible ways to ll the second
>   row are considered:
>
> 1; 2; : : : ; N
>   2; 3; : : : ; N; 1
>   3; 4; : : : ; N; 1; 2
>   |
>   N; 1; : : : ; ; N  1
>
> For instance, for the example above, we would consider each of the following as possibilities for the second row.
>
> 1 2 3 4
>   2 3 4 1
>   3 4 1 2
>   4 1 2 3
>
> Your task is to find the score for each of the above choices of the second row. In the
>   example above, you would evaluate the following four tables,
>
> 7 1 6 2
>   1 2 3 4
>   7 1 6 2
>   2 3 4 1
>   7 1 6 2
>   3 4 1 2
>   7 1 6 2
>   4 1 2 3
>   and compute scores 9, 10, 10 and 11, respectively
>
> Test data: N <= 200000
>   Time Limit: 2 seconds

Here is the obvious method:

Maintain two arrays A,B, Do the following n times

- add every element A[i] to B[i] and keep a variable max which stores the maximum value so far.
- print max
- loop through array B[i] and increment all the elements by 1, if any element is equal to N, set it equal to 1.

This method will have take O(n^2) time, the outer loop runs N times and there are two inner loops which run for N times each.

To reduce the time taken, we can find the maximum element M in the first row(in a linear scan), and then remove A[i] and B[i] whenever A[i] + N <= M + 1.
Because they will never be max.

But this method might perform better in the average case, the worst case time will still be O(N^2).

To find max in constant time i also considered using a heap, each element of the heap has two attributes, their original value and the value to be added. 
But still it will require a linear time to increment the value-to-be-added for all the elements of the heap for each of the n cases.
And so the time still remains O(N^2)

I am not able to find a method that will solve this problem faster than N^2 time which will be too slow as the value of N can be very large.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Downvoted for subject line unlikely to help future visitors to the site ("too localized").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also an O(n) algorithm. Using the same observations as in a previous answer:

> Now consider what happens to the column sums when you rotate the second row to the left (e.g. change it from 1,2,...,N to 2,3,...,N,1): Each column sum will increase by 1, except for one column sum which is decreased by N-1.
>
> Instead of modifying all the column sums, we can decrease the one column sum by N, and then take the maximum column sum plus 1 to find the new maximum of the column sums. So we only need to update one column instead of all of them.

The column where the maximum appears can only move to the left or jump back to the column with the overall maximum as we iterate over the possibilities of the second row. Candidate columns are the ones that were the temporary maximum in a left to right maximum scan.

1. calculate all the sums for the first choice of the second row (1, 2, ..., N) and store them in an array.
2. find the maximum in this array in a left to right scan and remember the positions of temporary maxima.
3. in a right to left pass the sums are now decreased by N. If this decreasing process reaches the max column, check if the number is smaller than the overall maximum - N, in this case the new max column is the overall maximum column and it will stay there for the rest of the loop. If the number is still larger than the previous maximum determined in step 2, the max column will stay the same for the rest of the loop. Otherwise, the previous maximum becomes the new max column.

Taking the example input 7,1,6,2 the algorithm runs as follows:
Step 1 calculates the sum 8,3,9,6
Step 2 finds the temporary maxima from left to right: 8 in col 1 and then 9 in col 3
Step 3 generates the results passing over the array from right to left

```
8 3 9 6 -> output 9 + 0 = 9
8 3 9 2 -> output 9 + 1 = 10
8 3 5 2 -> current max col is decreased, previous max 8 is larger and becomes current
           output 8 + 2 = 10
8 -1 5 2 -> output 8 + 3 = 11
```

Here is the algorithm in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N;
int A[200000];
int M[200000];

int main(){
    int i,m,max,j,mval,mmax;

    scanf("%d",&N);

    for(i = 0;i < N; i++){
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        A[i] = A[i]+i+1;
    }

    m = 0;
    max = 0;
    M[0] = 0;

    for(i = 1;i < N; i++){
        if(A[i] > A[max]){
            m++;
            M[m] = i;
            max = i;
        }
    }

    mval = A[max] - N;
    mmax = max;

    for(i = N-1,j = 0;i >=0;i --,j++){
        printf("%d ", A[max]+j);

        A[i] = A[i] - N;

        if(i == max){
            if (A[i] < mval) {
                max = mmax;
            } else if(m > 0 && A[i] < A[M[m-1]]){
                max = M[m-1];
                m--;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice, I thought an O(n) solution should be possible but didn't see the fact that the maximum will only move to the left.

Comment: "check if the number is still larger as the previous maximum determined in step 2" , The number will never be larger than the previous max, because it will be decreased by N.

Comment: Also could you please explain the 3rd step, i did not understand it.

Comment: Taking your example, the initial sums will be 8,3,9,6. Looking for max from left to right you first find 8 in col 1 and then 9 in col 3. I call 9 the current max and 8 the previous max. When we decrease col 3 by N we find 9-4=5 and this is smaller than 8 so our new max column is now col 1.

Comment: I'll add step 3 as it runs on the example data to the answer

Comment: for the input 9 3 5 12 16 10, your algorithm is outputting 21 22 18 13 14 15  when the actual output should be 21 22 18 18 19 20

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `O(n*logn)` solution:

Suppose you calculate all the column sums for a particular arrangement of the second row.

Now consider what happens to the column sums when you rotate the second row to the left (e.g. change it from `1,2,...,N` to `2,3,...,N,1`): Each column sum will increase by 1, except for one column sum which is decreased by N-1.

Instead of modifying all the column sums, we can decrease the one column sum by N, and then take the maximum column sum plus 1 to find the new maximum of the column sums. So we only need to update one column instead of all of them.

So our algorithm would be:

- Set the second row to be 1,2,...,N and calculate the sum of each column. Put all these sums in a max-heap. The root of the heap will be the largest sum.
- For `i` in 1 to `N`:

  - Decrease the value of the heap node corresponding to the `N-i` th column by `N`.
  - The new maximum column sum is the root of the heap plus `i`.

Each heap update takes `O(logn)` which leads to an `O(n*logn)` overall time.

Comment: How do we find the heap node corresponding to the n-1th column, wont that take linear time?

Comment: @A.06 You can have an additional array that maps a column number to a heap index, and make sure to update it whenever heap nodes are moved.

Comment: no, one can keep pointers to the heap nodes in an array to quickly find them.